# Dependent transactions in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here's my problem:

I have 2 tables A and B. I need to solve the below problem by using hibernate jpa entity manager.

In a single request I am sending data. First, I need to insert a row in table A where one id will be generated by a sequence generator (which is a primary key). Then in table b I need to insert the data which was sent in the request and the primary key generated above will act as a foreign key in table B.

Comment: Seems to me a simple transaction can handle that scenario. Have you tried it? What specific problems have you found?

Comment: i tried through  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) annotation but the problem over here is in table 2 i need to insert 2 rows ... there it is throwing primarykey constraint voilated exception... the exact thing wat am doign is ..

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you showed your code and mappings.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with one transaction as acdcjunior said. The Hibernate session waits to execute DML until the session commits (so it can reorder SQL actions) but you can tell it to go ahead and execute everything it has so far. The sequence number will be generated for you when the first insert executes.

If you call flush on the current session after saving A, that will cause the insert SQL for A to be executed on the database (without committing the transaction). Then Hibernate will populate the key field on your A entity with the generated key value and you can use that to populate the FK field on the B entity.

If you want to avoid going back to the database just to get a sequence number (which could get slow if you have a lot of inserts) then you may want to switch to a different sequence generator, such as the hilo sequence generator, which will preallocate sequence numbers for you.